# JavaScript only works when alert() is called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to send a `POST` request to a Java method that creates an account with the given form parameters in a database.
If the account is successfully created the method returns true, and then I should get redirected to a link. But the code below doesn't work unless the `alert("")` function is there.

I assume it has something to do with asynchronous mode, but I'm new to JavasScript and would really appreciate any help :)

Here's the code:

```
function createAccount(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var rpassword = document.getElementById("rpassword").value;
var emp_no = document.getElementById("emp_no").value;

xhr.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/di24_app/di24/create',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send('fname='+fname+'&surname='+surname+'&email='+email+'&password='+password+'&rpassword='+rpassword+'&emp_no='+emp_no);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if(this.responseText == "false"){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Error creating account!";
            document.getElementById("result").style.textAlign = "center";
        }
        else if(this.responseText == "true"){
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/di24_app/html/home_page/home.html";
        }
    }

}
alert("");
}
```

Comment: Can you show where and how you are calling `createAccount()`?
Also are there any error in the console, after calling the function, without the alert() ?

Comment: I am currently puzzled how this can work at all, since document.getElementsById
Does not exist. You cant get multiple elements by the Id, since an Id should be unique.

Comment: <button type ="submit" onclick="createAccount()">Create</button> this is how I call the function

Comment: Have you tried calling `xhr.send()` only after setting `xhr.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: Currently you directly invoke the function when creating the dom. Instead of onClick="createAccount()" you have to write onclick="createAccount". That way you won't invoke it directly, the onclick property should only get the function reference as a callback passed.

Comment: @DustingGogoll I retrieve the values using getElementsByName("abc")[0].value, but I changed it to getElementById("abd") for this questions and forgot to correct it :)

Comment: @CristianAnghel i see that you have `type="submit"` on the button, is your button placed inside a `<form/>` tag ?

Comment: @haim770 yes I have

Comment: @Dahou yes, it is inside a <form></form>

Comment: @CristianAnghel i think this is the issue, cause when a button with `type="submit"` is inside a `<form/>` the browser will automatically post the data and refresh your page, after clicking that button, i will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a button with type="submit" and `onclick="createAccount()"` is inside a `<form/>` , the browser will automatically post the data and refresh your page, after clicking that button, So the execution of the function `createAccount()` will never reach the end.

On the html button tag do this:
`<button type ="submit" onclick="return createAccount()">Create</button>`
add `return` before `createAccount()`

On the function createAccount() at the end add `return false`.

Returning a `false` when calling a method from a submit type button, will indicate to the browser to not automatically post form data.

```
function createAccount(){

....

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if(this.responseText == "false"){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Error creating account!";
            document.getElementById("result").style.textAlign = "center";
        }
        else if(this.responseText == "true"){
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/di24_app/html/home_page/home.html";
        }
    }

}
//alert("");
return false; // important
}
```

Comment: Great, No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback methods inside your onreadystatechange function like below;

```
function createAccount(successCallback, errorCallback) {
   ...

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if(this.responseText == "false"){
           errorCallback();
        }
        else if(this.responseText == "true"){
           successCallback();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call createAccount method with below two function params;

```
createAccount(
   function () { console.log('success') },
   function () { console.log('error') }
)
```

And you can write your dom manipulation codes into these callback functions.